# Ask the delegate to open a resource identified by a URL from outside AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code which asks the delegate to open a resource identified by a URL and want to have this code outside of the AppDelegate file i.e. in a different file:

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
               openURL:(NSURL *)url
     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
            annotation:(id)annotation {

        NSLog(@"url --> %@", url); 
        //Do something...
        return YES;
    }
```

It works correctly if it is in AppDelegate, but if I have this method in another file, it will simply not run.

To give more context of why I am using this approach, there is an auth process involved. So at some point in my app Safari opens and prompts the user with some credentials. 
Then I launch my app with the URL Scheme + some info, e.g. `myurl://someinfo`

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Could you explain it?

Comment: When I open my app using a URL Scheme this function gets called. But it only works if it is in my `AppDelegate.m` file. I want to make it work from another file in the same directory.

Comment: Ahh, well you have several options. You could define a delegate object with a custom class for example. Did you try using notifications with the `NSNotificationCenter`? That's a better option I believe.

Comment: @AlejandroIván There is no corresponding notification for this particular app delegate method. Of course an app specific one can be created and used.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I thought he could use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification and catch it in another objects.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I have not tried the `NSNotificationCenter` yet. To give more context of why I am using this approach, there is an auth process involved. So at some point in my app Safari opens and prompts the user with some credentials. Then I launch my app with the URL Scheme + some info, e.g. `myurl://someinfo`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván could you elaborate more on the other options you mentioned?

Comment: @AndresC.Viesca done, any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Seems using NSNotificationCenter could be the best fit for your requirement.

In AppDelegate post a notification using NSNotificationCenter

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
           sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"url --> %@", url);
    // Do something...
    // 1 - Post recieved URL by usig NSNotificationCenter
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"APP_LAUNCHED_BY_URL_SCHEMA_NOTIFICATION" object:url];
   return YES;
}
```

and in Your Custom class (for ex: ViewController) add below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // 2 - Add observer to the notification name posted from AppDelegate
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidLaunchedByURLSchemaNotification:) name:@"APP_LAUNCHED_BY_URL_SCHEMA_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}
-(void)appDidLaunchedByURLSchemaNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // 3 - Here you can get the URL Object posted with notification,you will get this Callback on every launch of your application using Your Custom URL Scheme by other applications.
    NSURL *url = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"url --> %@", url);
}
```

Remember to remove added observer in custom class's -dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

H2H,Have fun with coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is really similar to Naresh's answer, because all notifications from `NSNotificationCenter` work in the same way.

Basically, you will choose a name for the notification (for example: `@"NOTIFICACION_NAME"`) and then every object that you need to receive that event will subscribe to all notifications with that name.

So, in your app delegate you will post (e.g. "broadcast") a notification with the name:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
       openURL:(NSURL *)url
       sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // First, create a dictionary with all the data needed to pass.
    NSDictionary *notificationInfo = @{
                                        @"url"               : url,
                                        @"sourceApplication" : sourceApplication,
                                        @"annotation"        : annotation
                                      };
    // Post the notification to all objects that listen to it.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION_NAME"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:notificationInfo];
}
```

Now, we need to catch the notification in that other file that you need it. So:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {

    // Subscribe to the notifications called "NOTIFICATION_NAME"
    // The "object" parameter is nil so we get notification from all objects that post that particular notification name.
    // It could also be [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] to receive notifications only from the app delegate.
    // If you process the event in a UIViewController, do this in viewDidLoad instead of init.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(openedWithURLScheme:)
                                                 name:@"NOTIFICATION_NAME"
                                               object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Unsubscribe from all notifications at dealloc time. If you don't do this,
    // your app will crash when the app delegate posts the notifications
    // after this particular object was deallocated.
    // If it's a UIViewController, do this in viewDidUnload.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)openedWithURLScheme:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // The notification was received, so this method is called with the
    // notification object as a parameter. Now we get the dictionary
    // we sent with all the info.
    NSDictionary *notificationInfo = notification.userInfo;

    // Now get the data you need:
    NSURL *url = notificationInfo[@"url"];
    NSString *sourceApplication = notificationInfo[@"sourceApplication"];
    id annotation = notificationInfo[@"annotation"];

    // Do what you need with that info...
}
```

In simple words: When your app delegate receives that particular method, we **broadcast** (notify) the info received to every object that's "listening" (observing) that particular notification. It should be done using a `NSDictionary`.

For more info, read the [official documentation at Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/).

Answer (score -1):

Leave that code in AppDelegate and instead use that method in another class.

Define globally AppDelegate in AppDelegate.h like this

```
#define APP_DELEGATE ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

After doing this, you can call methods of AppDelegate.m anywhere in the code , like this:

```
[APP_DELEGATE methodYouWantToCall];
```

Comment: It's exactly the opposite. He wants the app delegate to inform other objects. In other words: delegate the business logic of that method to another object.

Comment: I thought he wanted to run that code from outside of AppDelegate file. That's what he said in his first line.

Comment: @AkashKR I am sorry it was not clear, I have edited the question to make it more clear :)